# Using LDAP to store C++ variables

Tags: c++, ldap

I am thinking to use LDAP to store my C++ variables. I want the C++ variables to initialize using the LDAP.
Have anyone worked on such things before? Feel free to share your opinions.

Comment: To be blunt, why?

Comment: Then use an LDAP library for C++. What's the problem?

Comment: @tadman The problem is that I have not used it before. I just wanted to know if it works the way I am thinking or not.

Comment: The problem is you've got to at least make an effort to solve your problem and find out how viable this is. We can't take you through this step-by-step. You're going to need to *try something* and see what happens.

Comment: @tadman sounds good :). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ldap is an active directory and I don't think this is what you want to use for your variables, ldap is mainly used to store credentials and other user based information. If you do want to use ldap for your variables it would take a lot of time to get it working and I would not recommend it. Ldap is also not nearly as fast as MySQL of mongodb. So use the things meant for it.

Comment: Actually, using an LDAP directory server to store program configuration data is not that unusual. It can be a handy way to centralize configuration that needs to be shared between a bunch of services on different hosts. I don't know if that's what the OP means by "variables," however. Also, I think I'd be inclined to challenge your assertion than an LDAP lookup will be slower than a database query. In a case like this, we would be looking up a specific data item, rather than executing a query. Of course, there are many other factors that would need to be considered.

Comment: @kevin you are indeed correct about ldap being better for specific lookups but if I am thinking about variables I'm thinking about just simple key value storage and in that case you probably want to get them all in one request so therefore I would suggest MySQL or if it IS just key value storage I would suggest redis with backups enabled if the variables must be kept

Comment: To be honest, it isn't clear to me what the OP actually wants to achieve, so I suppose discussing the merits of different ways of achieving it is to put the cart before the horse ;)

Comment: Hahah, true so for know let settle this and let's just assume we are both correct